# Redefining Devise user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to redefine the user creation in Devise in a way that allows me to transfer data from a `Guest` user to the created user.

Can I just override the  `new` and `create` methods in my `UsersController` as such

```
def new
  @user = user.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  #method to move data from Guest to new User
  @user.create
end
```

and then create a `new.html.haml` `form_for` that takes the user's email and password? Will doing this mess up any sort of Devise security features, etc?

Comment: the code that creates devise users is under the registrations controller so that's what you have to change.  having said that, you'd want to copy https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb to your application under device/registrations_controller and update the new and create method.  Take note that this is *IF* you are not using custom devise controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common practice to override default devise controllers and add custom functionality to them.
I think it will feet you needs of transferring data from guest to registered user.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

This approach is well-documented, and has many refers at StackOverflow.